# Why kotlin jackson can't deserialize list

Tags: exception, kotlin, jackson, jvm

I have a function:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any>parse(result: String): T  = mapper.readValue<Response<T>>(result).someValue
```

When I pass a list type, e.g. `List<MyClass>`, and try to get some item from it, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3" 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to MyClass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the type to the `readValue`-function, otherwise Jackson has no way to know to which type it should transform to. By default jackson then just returns a map with keys and its values.

So for your particular problem you may just make the `parse`-`function` `inline` and add a `reified` to your passed type. This ensures, that the actual type is also passed to Jackson. See also [reified types in the kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters). Alternatively you pass the actual type (either using `TypeReference` or the class itself if it's not generic).

Previously this answer also contained a general information how to deserialize a json list to an actual one, which I will leave here for reference:

```
mapper.readValue(result, object : TypeReference<List<MyClass>>() {})
```

or if you use [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin):

```
mapper.readValue<List<MyClass>>(result)
```

Applied to your function that could look like the following:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any>parse(result: String): T  = mapper.readValue(result, object : TypeReference<T>() {})
```

or using jackson-module-kotlin:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any>parse(result: String): T  = mapper.readValue(result)
```

Calling it would then just be:

```
val yourObjList = parse<List<MyClass>>(yourJson)
// or
val yourObjList : List<MyClass> = parse(yourJson)
```

Note that I used `reified` (which implies `inline`). If you do not use `reified` the actual type is not passed on to jackson-module-kotlin's reified methods.

Comment: I edited post. Variant with jackson kotlin module doesnt work

Comment: did you try with `reified`?

Comment: Same error? Or a different one? Did you pass the whole type from outside or a mixture?

Comment: Yes, still throw ClassCastException.

Comment: I have getUpdates fun, that call request fun with List<Update> type. That call parse fun with Response<T>. request and parse are inline with reified typevar

Comment: I don't get what you mean.. can you post the beginning of your JSON and maybe also the outermost corresponding type? It should work with the code as shown.. are you sure that you need to wrap it as `Response`?

Comment: In this case```{"ok": true, "some info":"about response", "result": [{"update":"objects"}]}``` But `response.result` may have any type.

Comment: Assuming something like `class Response<T>(val ok : Boolean, ..., val result : T)` and appropriate constructor, the following should deserialize it: `parse<Response<List<Update>>>(json)`.. note that I write it with my smartphone now... could be that some minor things aren't ok.. but with the reified variant it should work or give rather another error...

Comment: What you could also do: try to serialize a similar object first and look what you get..

Comment: When i serialize object, i have this json `{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":10,"message":null}]}`. When i try desialize, i have that error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to ru.kolay.xxx.types.Update at ru.kolay.xxx.MainKt.main(main.kt)` My code: https://pastebin.com/bSgTXUVG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179239/discussion-between-kolay-and-roland).